# How to tell svn to not manage history for one file

Tags: svn

I don't know whether SVN has this feature, How do I tell svn to not maintain the history of changes for a file but it should have only the latest version of the file. Of course this is not the work of a version control, but it will be useful if I want to have some binary files within the repo without versioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Everything in SVN is built around the concept of not losing data. I think you are looking for a backup solution?

You could SVN ignore the file, and then have your build script copy the file from a copy location when a user has just checked out the repository.

Comment: ok thanks. Is there any option to run a command - after commit?

Comment: @Prabu: I think you are looking for the post-commit hook functionality.  Here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html